# SSIS using a different query plan than when I running through SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, ssis, sql-execution-plan, attunity

I have an SSIS package that grabs some data from Oracle.
For some reason, when I run the query through SSIS, it appears that I am getting a different query plan than I do when I run it through SQL developer.

Originally, it was running very quick through SSIS, grabbing all data in about 8 seconds. But now, it is taking about 40 seconds. From monitoring sessions in Oracle, I can see that it is doing a full table scan of my detail table, whereas when I run it through SQL developer, it is doing an index scan.

Why would I get different results when running through SSIS? I am using the Attunity connector for Oracle.

Comment: How recently have you collected statistics on the tables involved in this query?

Comment: I personally observed that OLEDB works faster than attunity. May be that also hold true for you.

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing to me.